# Windows Phone 8.1 - ContentDialog never gets hidden

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

In my Windows Phone 8.1 app I use a ContentDialog to display some data. When I calle contentDialog.ShowAsync(); it shows as expected, but when I try to hide it, the dialog keeps on screen.

My code is as follows:

```
StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
ProgressBar progressBarDialog = new ProgressBar();
progressBarDialog.Width = 300;
progressBarDialog.Height = 10;
progressBarDialog.IsIndeterminate = true;

TextBlock textBlockDialog = new TextBlock();
textBlockDialog.Text = "Loading...";
textBlockDialog.FontSize = 17;
textBlockDialog.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
textBlockDialog.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

stackPanel.Children.Add(progressBarDialog);
stackPanel.Children.Add(textBlockDialog);

ContentDialog contentDialog = new ContentDialog();
contentDialog.Content = stackPanel;
SolidColorBrush color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
color.Opacity = 0.7;
contentDialog.Background = color;
contentDialog.Margin = new Thickness(0, 250, 0, 0);

await contentDialog.ShowAsync();
//Perform long operations
contentDialog.Hide();
```

So, the dialog shows without any problem, but it never gets hidden.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there something in your Content dialog that should hide it? As I think your program never gets to `contentDialog.Hide();` as it's awaiting dialog to close.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this:

```
var t =  contentDialog.ShowAsync();
t.Cancel();
```